# Filtering An Array (JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I am having trouble filtering through this array that contains objects. An explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Instructions:

// Using filter(), return only your friends of the array of people below. 
//Assign it to a variable called 'trueFriends'.

My Solution:

```
var trueFriends = [];

peopleIknow.filter(function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < peopleIknow.length; i++){
    if (peopleIknow[i].friend == true){
      trueFriends.push(peopleIknow[i]);
    }
  }
});

var peopleIknow = [
  { name: "Steve", friend: true },
  { name: "Dan", friend: false },
  { name: "Bart", friend: true },
  { name: "Sarah", friend: false },
  { name: "Michelle", friend: false },
  { name: "Holly", friend: true }
];
```

Comment: The issue with filter is that it expects the callback to be called for each item in the array. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter has a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `for` loop in `filter`. Filter iterates through the array and return all the elements based on condition

```js
var peopleIknow = [
  { name: "Steve", friend: true },
  { name: "Dan", friend: false },
  { name: "Bart", friend: true },
  { name: "Sarah", friend: false },
  { name: "Michelle", friend: false },
  { name: "Holly", friend: true }
];

var o = peopleIknow.filter(e=> e.friend );

console.log(o)
```

Comment: `e.friend === true` is not nesessary as e.friend itself is boolean.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop inside a `filter` function defeats the purpose - try just using the `filter` function to iterate. You also shouldn't try to `filter` over an array before the array has been declared.

The first argument to the `filter` function is the item being iterated over, and you're only interested in the `friend` property, so you can extract only the `friend` property. If `friend` is true, then you want to return `true` to the `filter` function, so that it's included in your final array - else, return `false`. So, just return the `friend` property as is.

```js
const peopleIknow = [
  { name: "Steve", friend: true },
  { name: "Dan", friend: false },
  { name: "Bart", friend: true },
  { name: "Sarah", friend: false },
  { name: "Michelle", friend: false },
  { name: "Holly", friend: true }
];

const trueFriends = peopleIknow.filter(({ friend }) => friend);
console.log(trueFriends);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `filter()` as well as [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do the same.

Here is using `reduce()` method. Both reduce and filter runs for the function once for each element of the array.

```js
var trueFriends = [];
var peopleIknow = [
  { name: "Steve", friend: true },
  { name: "Dan", friend: false },
  { name: "Bart", friend: true },
  { name: "Sarah", friend: false },
  { name: "Michelle", friend: false },
  { name: "Holly", friend: true }
];
trueFriends = peopleIknow.reduce((acc,i) => {
  i.friend && acc.push(i);// same as if(i.friend) then push
  return acc;
},[]);
console.log(trueFriends);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Luca. When I answered, I just saw that there were 4 other answers just for a simple fix and with an explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

Don't run a for loop in your filter function. Filter is so easy to use. If the result of the function passed to filter is true it adds that element to the return value. This is what you are looking for!

```js
var peopleIknow = [
  { name: "Steve", friend: true },
  { name: "Dan", friend: false },
  { name: "Bart", friend: true },
  { name: "Sarah", friend: false },
  { name: "Michelle", friend: false },
  { name: "Holly", friend: true }
];

var trueFriends = [];

//                                         only the friends where person.friend is truthy 
trueFriends = peopleIknow.filter(person => person.friend);

console.log(trueFriends);
```

Answer (score 0):

You created filter and apply what the filter do in it, this code will work as you like.

```js
var trueFriends = [];
var peopleIknow = [
      { name: "Steve", friend: true },
      { name: "Dan", friend: false },
      { name: "Bart", friend: true },
      { name: "Sarah", friend: false },
      { name: "Michelle", friend: false },
      { name: "Holly", friend: true }
    ];
    
   trueFriends = peopleIknow.filter(function(item){
      return item.friend});
    console.log(trueFriends)
```